# SAS... Have a string with two lines of data, trying to get second line only

Tags: split, sas

I have a blob of data from another database that I imported into SAS. The blob of data has multiple lines that starts with tags. I am able to write a piece of code to look for each tag and append them to a table column. Problem is, one of the tags has multiple lines of data (separated by carriage return/line feed) and I do not care about the first line. I only want the second line of data added to the table column (example below :NADR:). Can someone tell me how to modify this line of code to only look for the second line?

**Example:**

:NADR:SE12345

ADVANCED AUTO

:DF1:10/7/2018

**Code:**

Case When find(t1.Blob,":NADR:") > 0 then Strip(Substr(Substr(t1.Blob,find(t1.Blob,":NADR:")+6,300), 1, find(Substr(t1.Blob,find(t1.Blob,":NADR:")+6,300),":")-1)) End as Name

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `scan` function to grab parts of a text.  This example demonstrates using two different hex characters (those cr & lf) as part delimiters.

```
part2 = scan(blob,2,'0a0d'x);
```

Default behavior is that consecutive delimiters in the text in any order are considered a single delimiter.  The `m` modifier in the fourth argument (not used above) of `scan` can change that behavior.

Comment: Thank you, i took your example and made the following code and it worked.



When find(t1.Blob,":NADR:") > 0 then scan(strip(Substr(Substr(t1.Blob,find(t1.Blob,":NADR:")+5,500), 1, find(Substr(t1.Blob,find(t1.Blob,":NADR:")+5,500),":")-1)),2,'0a0d'x)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can import each line individually and then just delete the lines with tags you don't want. For example:

```
if find(t1.Blob,":NADR:") > 0 then delete;
```

And the line with "Advanced Auto" is its own record. Unless something else about your data structure doesn't allow that.